# Can image links have different style from regular images?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, hyperlinks, images

Image links and regular images look exactly alike, making it difficult for someone to figure out that there's a link there. I'd like to suggest a minor style change, something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/36b39/2/

There are a few different options, but they are basically:

- Images links can have borders: this would make it easier to see, without hovering the mouse on them, that they are links. The downside is that it might not look good.
- Image links will generate a drop shadow when someone hovers over them. Yes, I realize the cursor changes, but this would make it clearer.

What do you think?

PS: I realize SO doesn't use images a whole lot, but the newer SE sites might.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Meta Stack Overflow has image-link styling already:

#### Image without link

> [image: Image no link]

#### Image with link

> [image: Image with link]

I could've sworn other sites, particularly Gaming, had the same style, but after testing a few sites now, it appears only Meta Stack Overflow has it.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a good idea.**

I think the [current styling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108056/153008) that "underlines" the image looks ugly and broken. I was actually trying to figure out how that artifact got into one of my posts, then I realized it was the result of a `border-bottom` style being used to produce a dotted underline, instead of the expected `text-decoration: underline;`.

This is all fine and good for text-based hyperlinks, but we can do better for images. Perhaps a 3D shadow effect to suggest "popping" out of the page, like we do for hoverable gravatars? I think this works well enough as a hint now, and would be even better if something like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189343/images-should-be-automatically-rescaled-and-the-full-size-put-into-a-lightbox) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151793/support-showing-image-in-original-size-in-overlay) is ever implemented.

Here's just a simple demonstration of the effect (I'm no graphic designer and only pretending to be a web developer):

[image]

```
box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px #888;
```

(plus all the vendor-specific prefix versions, if y'all still do that)

Comment: Nice, but many Mac screen captures [already have a (ugly) shadow](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9dDh1.png). That might make this confusing (and even worse looking)?