# Support showing image in original size in overlay

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks, images, uploader

It would be nice to support showing images in their original size when they where automatically resized because they are too big to fit in a question or answer ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949132/need-to-normalize-wsdl-file)).

I envision it just like in blogs or facebook: You can click on the image and it is shown in its original size in an overlay.

Comment: FWIW Quora does implement it. I can see pros, I don't see any cons.

Comment: Hi! I noticed that the example here leads to a deleted question, most likely because this request is a few years old.  I know you're busy and it's not a big deal, but I was wondering if you might be willing to link to a different example.  I'd like to see an overlay too, but in the meantime, I hope this change makes your life here easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

We haven't implemented an overlay (the community was more divided on this), but from now on, the image uploader automatically wraps images in a link to themselves, which looks like this and should make your life easier:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: Success!]

---

[Balpha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) is to thank for this change.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this only when the image width exceeds the text width, please? Currently, it looks really ridiculous that a 100x50 px image gets hyperlinked to ... itself in the same size.

Comment: @yo' I agree. I posted several pictures well below the text body width and I had to remove the links because I kept thinking the images would actually link somewhere. A link should should only serve to provide extra information, not repeat the exact same image, in a new window. It adds no value. It makes sense to provide a link for oversized images.

Comment: This is _such a sad excuse_ (as a replacement) for _so basic of a feature_.

Comment: @Thomas, what about the MILLIONS of old posts created "before".  They do NOT seem inherit this "feature".

Comment: Just to voice some dissent: I hate this feature. It would be nice to be able to disable it in some way. Clickety click, clickety click - oops, why is *that* image a link to nowhere?

Comment: @yo, you are right that - by default - inserting an image via the toolbar of the Stack Exchange Markdown editor, a click link to the image itself will ***always*** be inserted. Personally, I don't mind. But for anyone disturbed by it, the behavior for "small pictures" is easy to change manually. Simply replace `[![blah][1]][1]` by `![blah][1]` and the image will not be clickable any more! - If you want to deepen your understanding on how this works, I recommend reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2191, possibly including the reference links at the bottom.

Answer (score 12):

This is a good idea. I'd like to see it on the site, without having to right-click, open in new tab or so. Just a click on the image and a nice fancybox (or similar) opens up:

[image]

It could look like [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) or [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

It's really annoying to have images scaled down so that they aren't well readable anymore, and having to right-click, copy image URL, open new tab, paste, enter in order to see the full size image.

Answer (score 3):

Your browser already supports that.  Right-click the image, click "Open Link in New Tab".  You get a zoom cursor in IE, Firefox, Safari and Chrome (quite possibly others).

Comment: That's how I do it right now. However, the usability of that approach is meager at best.

Comment: And: you can actually zoom, as a bonus. Works for me indeed.

Comment: I dispute your "facts".  In IE, if you right-click an image, the "Open Link in New Tab" menu item is disabled (dimmed/gray) *unless the image **is a link*** (e.g., as done with the `[![...][1]][1]` markdown).  (I'm using IE 11.)

Comment: That is relying upon browser functionality and requires an extra click. Those extra clicks soon add up... :-)