# Auto zoom of screenshot in questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Support showing image in original size in overlay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151793/support-showing-image-in-original-size-in-overlay)

There are many sites with auto-zooming feature (lightbox) of screenshot/pic (e.g facebook), why can't we implement the same in Stackexchange sites? It will be convenient to users who browse questions and answers, for example see this [question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/error-code-32999-while-testing-sample-app-at-loadrunner).

Here i uploaded a screenshot, but while reading the question the user may feel inconvenient while looking over an pic/screenshot... So why can't we use autozoom of screenshot for pictures/screenshots on stackexchange sites.

Comment: @Bart the answer provided there only work for stackoverflow,whereas other stackexchange sites doesnt support that feautre

Comment: It's the exact same feature request. The answer given doesn't matter all that much. There is no need for a new question with the exact same request.

Comment: As an aside: please don't use screen captures for error messages. Future visitors won't be able to find those by searching for the text. Also as an aside: please crop screen captures to whatever part is relevant. And yet another aside: please note that nice changes Tomáš made to your question. We like proper punctuation, proper uppercased sentences, and "I" rather than "i". Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that ALL your posts here have been edited. Please review those edits and take those as some feedback? Don't let others do the work for you! Thanks.