# Markdown images should clickable by default

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images, markdown-rendering

Imagine a person posting a diagram within a Stack Exchange question.  Typically they wind up with markdown like this:

```
### ![enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvhYx.jpg
```

The problem is that many images are too small when scaled to a normal screen, and we need to click them to make the image large enough to read.  Usually this means I replace the aforementioned markdown with an `<img>` wrapped in `<a>` tags:

```
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvhYx.jpg">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvhYx.jpg">
</a>
```

That html makes the image clickable:

[image]

#### FEATURE REQUEST

That's too much work.  This is a rather common use-case; markdown images should be rendered as clickable by default.

Comment: If nothing else, at least make it clickable when/if the system scales it down.

Comment: The even better solution would be to use one of the auto-generated smaller versions of the image in the post and link it to the full-sized one. There's a feature request for that around somewhere, I think.

Comment: Why not `[![][1]][1]` for a shorthand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support showing image in original size in overlay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151793/support-showing-image-in-original-size-in-overlay)

Comment: By default? No. If you want to make them clickable, the system needs to check the image size and determine if it's too wide to fit into the post without being resized. Make *that* clickable. I think a bunch of normal sized images that weren't resized being linked to their source would be a bit irritating.

Comment: @animuson, I would humbly dispute the conclusion that this is a duplicate of the question in [Aaron's coment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222400/markdown-images-should-clickable-by-default#comment723224_222400), since that feature request was for all images (regardless of markdown), and this feature request is specific to markdown.  It won't bother me to leave it as dup, but it thought it was at least worth pointing out

Comment: Yes! I'm bored of doing this manually.

Comment: @Qantas That's what I do