# "Mobile web refresher, part 2" seems to break image sizing when answers have clickable images (Firefox Mobile)

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web, markdown-rendering

It seems that something about [Mobile web refresher, part 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237518/mobile-web-refresher-part-2) broke rendering of [clickable markdown images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222400/markdown-images-should-clickable-by-default#comment723221_222400) in Firefox / Firefox Mobile.

In the example below, I built a clickable markdown image with `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`, where `![enter image description here][1]` is a markdown hyperlink to the original-sized image.

Testing with Firefox Mobile 31.0 on Android "KitKat" 4.4.2 (Samsung Galaxy S4) produced the results shown in the examples below.

**Example 1**: when you make an image clickable in an answer, the answer's mobile image sizing breaks (and text renders off the screen), as shown in this screen-capture from Firefox Mobile:

[image]

You can reproduce the problem by checking FF mobile rendering of the [answer which inspired this bug report](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/10295/775).

**Example 2**: the same Firefox Mobile rendering of an answer without a clickable image renders without problems in Firefox Mobile:

[image]

NOTE: This seems to be a bug in all Firefox versions... Chrome / Safari Mobile don't seem to suffer from the problem.

Comment: Works fine on ios7

Comment: It also works fine in Chrome... but AFAIK, FF Mobile is a supported browser, right?  Is this something SE will consider fixing, or are you contending that this is a browser bug?

Comment: i'm trying to make a reasonable effort to support it, but its not a supported browser, since it has a tiny user base. mostly, issues that are shared with the desktop version.

Comment: it took me a while to understand what you meant. text wrapping and links are ok. images are not resized, instead.

Comment: Mea Culpa, I'm a network engineer... as such, my web development IQ occasionally suffers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens also with the desktop version of Firefox, as it doesn't respect the css `max-width` property. Fun.

<del>This will be fixed in the next deployment.</del> I was optimistic, I will need to look at it a bit more.

---

It's a browser quirk. Opera and Firefox do not work properly when a `max-width` element is inside a `display: table-cell;` element. For some reason they are not able to calculate the correct container size -- which is strange because the correct size is calculated when `width` is used.

[See some discussion about this on our site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923710/why-do-firefox-and-opera-ignore-max-width-inside-of-display-table-cell).

[Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975632).

Comment: Question is, is this a bug in Firefox? If so maybe better wait for them to fix it?

Comment: Caniuse says it's supported in FF. Looks like an FF bug.