# Is there a way to include a picture that gets bigger when clicked on?

Tags: support, images

I've been taking screenshots and adding them to posts but it sometimes is too small to properly see. Is there a way that the image could be clickable so that it could get bigger?

[Example question with picture.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60842/tail-recursive-sort)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189343/images-should-be-automatically-rescaled-and-the-full-size-linked-or-put-into-a-l

Answer (score 8):

Like this?

[image]

All you need to do is wrap your image with a link to it. Here's the Markdown:

```
[![enter image description here][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhGOD.png)

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhGOD.png
```

Comment: I was hoping I could press `esc` to close it, but that's an ok solution.

Comment: @Celeritas Additionally, you can also utilize [imgur's thumbnail api](https://api.imgur.com/models/image) to get different size thumbnails for your image (for example: `m` for the actual image, `l`/`h` for the link)

Comment: You could also write this as `[![Image][1]][1]` to avoid duplicating the URL.

Comment: Yep, weird url duplication ø_O Worth noting that appending `m` and `s` to the filename produces `medium` and `small` versions: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KhGODm.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/KhGODs.png