# Please add the markdown to make an image link to itself

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks, images

I can insert an image like so:

```
![Desc Text][1]

   [1]: http://www.funnycatpix.com/_pics/What_Are_You_Doing522.jpg
```

I can also link to said image:

```
[![Desc Text][1]][1]

   [1]: http://www.funnycatpix.com/_pics/What_Are_You_Doing522.jpg
```

And you can click the image to open in a new tab (useful for big images).

Can some markdown be added to do this? I'm thinking of this sort of syntax:

```
!![Desc Text][1]

   [1]: http://www.funnycatpix.com/_pics/What_Are_You_Doing522.jpg
```

Double `!` or maybe some other symbol combo.

Comment: Given that we will probably end up with [common mark](http://commonmark.org/), making our own extensions doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Oded Does it exist in common mark? Or can it be added when we get common mark?

Comment: I've changed the title, because there's no way to do it currently; moreover you've already phrased it as a feature request.

Comment: @Tim - the way to do it in common mark is [essentially your second code block](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.19/#example-436). Again, with a spec, adding our own (probably incompatible) extensions is not a good idea.

Comment: I don't understand the question completely. Do you just ask for a shortcut to write `[![...][1]][1]` as `!![...][1]`? Or is there more to the feature you propose?

Comment: @ChristianRau yes that's what im asking.

Comment: Hmm, seems easy enough to achieve, especially given that one shouldn't need this too often. Who really wants to do that certainly *knows that* he wants to do it and should be able to put those additional 3 symbols with ease.

Comment: For large images, one might actually want a thumbnail [by suffixing some `m` or `l`](http://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs), hence the URL for the image would be different from the URL to open the original image. See [Please do something to encourage people to scale down their giant heavyweight photos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/), [Can automatic loading of giant images be solved?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163563/) and [Images should be automatically rescaled and the full size linked or put into a lightbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189343/).

Comment: Linking [is done automatically now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151793/support-showing-image-in-original-size-in-overlay/261182#261182).