# What happened to the image syntax?

Tags: support, markdown, images, uploader

I have noticed recently that the syntax for an image has changed recently. What I remember (and still works) is this:

```
![Image description][2]
```

But now, it looks like this:

```
[![Image description][2]][2]
```

What happened? Why does it look like this?

Comment: [Yes, it's intentional and was recently implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261182/21960).

Comment: Something like this HTML code: `<a href="something"><img src="source"></a>`, so that when you click the image, it opens up the link in the `<a>` tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We recently made a change so that the image uploaded [automatically links the image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259580/please-add-the-markdown-to-make-an-image-link-to-itself) too, so that users can easily click on the image to see the larger version of it due to it being very common to upload larger images that then get resized down in the post.

You're just seeing two syntaxes getting mixed together: the image syntax *inside* the link syntax,

Comment: That makes sense. Well thought out :)