# Fix the duplicated markup for embedded images

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks, images

Some time ago (I want to say around the time that new profiles were rolled out on Stack Overflow), I noticed a bug appeared in the post editor, and it has persisted to this day.

When you want to add an embedded link, that still works fine, you get the `![enter description here][1]` code. However, when you embed an *image* into your post, you end up with this duplicated markup:

`[![enter image description here][1]][1]`

Removing the extra set of `[]` and `[1]` to make the markup match that of normal links (and image link markup of the past) will not result in the loss of the image, so I think it's pretty clear that this is an unintended bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug. It was an [intentional change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261180) so that large images that render too small to be useful would be linked back to the source image, which makes it much easier for users to get to it without having to right click and do other things just to open it up.

Comment: TIL... I wish that were an opt-in option though...

Comment: @TylerH Why do you want it opt in? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm just obsessive about the extra markup for what I think is an unnecessary feature, considering right-click -> view image already existed.